# How do you set the tracking interval in ESRI Workforce?

Tags: arcgis-online, workforce

I am using ESRI Workforce (beta) along with Collector for a Public Works project.  I have created a Workforce App and enabled location tracking.  My problem is the location tracking seems to be taking the GPS reading and plotting a point every minute, but at this interval I end up with way too many points and I keep getting the "Layer Can Not Draw Too Many Points" error.  My question is how do I turn the interval to say 15 minutes or 30 minutes.  I have been in the project settings and in the layer settings for each of my layers and I can not find anywhere to change the ping interval.

Answer (score 1):

In the current Beta, we don't provide a way to change the Update Interval for Location Tracking through the Workforce web app.  We will be providing this capability at the 1.0 release.

Your other option is to edit the json of the Workforce Project item, for example, through ago-assistant.com

Craig